# Random page generation excluding already generated options in php

Tags: php, mysql, random

What I want to achieve is to make a webpage which every time generates different content from MySQL DB. But when I use the rand() function, some options can repeat. So what I want to do is make rand() function with dynamic array "exceptions" that updates every time when the webpage content is generated, so every option is displayed to user only once.

Let's say I have 5 different options:
1,2,3,4,5

When the rand() function chooses **3** next time there will be no chance for getting **3** as a result..

```
function randWithout($from, $to, array $exceptions) {
sort($exceptions); 
$number = rand($from, $to - count($exceptions));
foreach ($exceptions as $exception) {
    if ($number >= $exception) {
        $number++; 
    } else  {
        break;
    }
}

    return $number;
}

    $exceptions = array("3","4");
    $random = randWithout(1, $num_rows, $exceptions);
```

This does what I want, but I want the array "$exceptions" to update every time.

Is there a way to do this by using sessions or some other options? I don't want to use another MySQL table.  I want it to be fast and simple.

Comment: Storing the array in `$_SESSION` would work fine.

Comment: try using mt_rand(), gives better random

Comment: you could use a pseudo random number generator like [LFSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register) ... this way you would not have to remember all exceptions... just the seed and the last generated value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Sessions. Sessions are used for data persistence. start your php file like this:

```
<?php session_start();
//your code
```

Save your exceptions in a session variable :

```
$_SESSION['exceptions']='exceptions Array';
```

Every time user visits a page add that to the session.

suppose you want to add '5' to it.

Hers updated code

```
<?php session_start();
function randWithout($from, $to) {
global $exceptions;
sort($exceptions); 
$number = rand($from, $to - count($exceptions));
foreach ($exceptions as $exception) {
    if ($number >= $exception) {
        $number++; 
    } else  {
        break;
    }
}

    return $number;
}

if(isset($_SEEION['exceptions'])){
$exceptions =$_SESSION['exceptions'];
}

$random = randWithout(1, $num_rows);
$exceptions[]=$random;
$_SESSION['exceptions']=$exceptions;
```

Comment: I was also thinking.. is there a way to make the array reset when all combinations are reached ?

Comment: Or.. can the session be "destroyed" after some time ? like cookies.. I don't want to use cookies as some visitors may have them turned off..

Comment: ya session_destroy(); and sessions are user specific..all destroyed when browser closes.. so need to do specifically

Answer (score 0):

This general question has been answered before.  See [How to generate a list of unique random numbers?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/how-to-generate-a-list-of-unique-random-numbers/1390#1390).  Assign each of your possible pages a number and pick one using an appropriate method.